# Map marker displays locally but not on live site

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've been dealing with `Google Maps` for few days and now I get this weird "bug".
I got a listener that every time I press on the map, a blue marker appears...

However, it happens only when I run my HTML file from my hard disk. Once I run it through my server the blue marker doesn't appear. I have no idea why.

The part of the code that does it looks like this:

```
//the listener that activates the function if I click on the map
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) 
{
    setAddress(event.latLng);
});  

//a global marker - because I want a different one if I press another time on the screen  
var marker2= new google.maps.Marker(
{
    map:map,
    title:"title",
    icon:'blue_markerA.png'
});  

//set the marker to the exact location...  
function setAddress(location) 
{
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
    parseFloat(location.lat()),parseFloat(location.lng()));

    marker2.setPosition(point);
}
```

Comment: did you upload the image(blue_markerA.png) too?

Comment: Of course....  like I said. when I run the html on my hardisk it  works fine.  the problem happens when I run it on the server...and fo course the server has the image as well..

Comment: When you say the image is on the server, this question cannot be answered by the given informations. We need more code, or better a link to the page.

Comment: Another option: debug the problem by removing the custom icon (the line "icon:'blue_markerA.png'" and the preceding comma), if it works then the problem is the icon is missing.